# No C experience, using Xcode AppleScriptObjC

Tags: terminal, applescript, xcode8, applescript-objc

Trying to get variable result from bash terminal and store in Xcode property variable.  No C experience, Xcode project is in AppleScript.

Comment: The shell script is getting a lot of variables from the Mac OS, sw_vers, curl from external databases, system setup, user input (I would like to do this in Xcode instead of shell script.  This is in my shell script "OSVERS=$(sw_vers -productVersion | awk -F. '{print $2}')" and would like to pass that back to an Xcode variable if that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the software version directly in AppleScript. The equivalent to your shell script is

```
set minor to (system attribute "sys2") as text
```

Comment: That's one problem solved!  Thanks.  The shell script is quite complex and binds the Mac to AD, installs some software via shell commands etc so there are many more variables from the script that I want to port from the script into Xcode to to display or edit in the GUI.  That's the part that I am stuck on. EX: the Domain and Domain OU's are options in the shell script now and I want to input those in the Xcode GUI properties and use them in the shell environment with the scutil command, so honestly I want to move variables both ways, from Xcode properties to Shell variables & vice versa

Comment: Use `do shell script`. The argument is passed to `stdin` and `stdout` is passed as the result.

Comment: I'm not sure how to implement that into my Xcode project AppleScript handlers....  Any hints?

Comment: [AppleScript Language Guide: do shell script](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW40) and [TN2065](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2065/_index.html)